# How to store and reproduce jQuery events

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am trying to store jQuery events in DB.

```
//Calling this Function On Click 

function trackevent(event){
    window.events.push(event)
}

$.each(window.events, function(i, item){
    console.log(i +" - "+ $.parseJSON(item));
});
```

Events got stored to array. That's cool, but if I am trying to loop through `window.events` I can't get the jQuery event JSON back. I can't figure out my mistake. Any suggestions will be helpful.

[image]

I am getting this error , if I changed parseJSON to JSON.stringify

```
$.each(window.events, function(i, item){
    console.log(i +" - "+ JSON.stringify(item));
});
```

[image]

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.events = []
// Function to enable the hidden checkbox button
$(".answers_checkbox").click(function(){
    current_click = $(this).attr("data-attr");

    // If the Hidden checkbox is Checked , it means its already selected (blue)
    if($("."+this.id).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        $(this).css('background-image', '');
    } else {
        // Changing the Background Image to current_click option
        $(this).css('background-image',"url('/assets/choice_buttons/choice"+current_click+"_Sq_Blue.png')");
    }

    $("."+this.id).attr('checked',!$("."+this.id).attr('checked'));
    trackevent(event);
});

function trackevent(event){
    window.events.push(event)
}

});

// Function to Save Events
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    $.each(window.events, function(i, item){
        console.log(i +" - "+ item);
    });
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl The first function is a click handler. This means that the argument passed for `event` will be an event object.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle. Going to have problems stringifying an event object due to functions in it

Comment: I created JSfiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/HjcGT/   
Basically , I need to store jQuery Event attributes to an array and loop through it.( to store in DB )

Comment: This lib can help you in your task: https://github.com/xk/JASON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseJSON` parses a **string** of JSON and returns an object. You're not supposed to pass it an object.

Since you're logging to the console anyway, you might as well log the complete object instead of a string representation:

```
console.log(i, item);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/HjcGT/1/

Comment: Hi Asad , I am getting this error after changing it to JSON.stringify  **Uncaught TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.**

Comment: @Senthil Can you please post the code which causes the error?

Comment: @Senthil No, the code where you have `selectionDirection`, not the code I have posted.

Comment: Sorry I created JSFiddle .

Comment: Thanks Asad, its working in jsfiddle. But there is some problem in my code, still its printing as string. Please check above new image . I pasted My complete code , I am looping this window variable in page unload.

Comment: @Senthil You are using `+` which gets the string representation of the object and concatenates it. Use `,` like in my example.